# In order to make a PDF document accessible can I just convert to an image and include all document text in an alt attribute?

Tags: html, accessibility

In order to bring our digital documents into compliance with web accessibility standards, we need to find a way to easily add readable text to our documents. Would it be acceptable to pull text from pdfs, convert them to jpg and add the text to the alt attribute?

Comment: Are you converting a sentence at a time, or the entire document at one shot? A sentence at a time is probably okay (still not great but okay), but the entire document is not. That would force someone to sit through a read-out of the entire document just because they wanted some information from the end of page 2. Also, if there is structure to the document (headings, tables, diagrams) then just the text is not sufficient.

Comment: How do you plan to "pull" text from those PDF files? If you can do that, why not create a truly accessible alternative? The `alt` attribute is intended for ***short** text alternatives* to images, not for entire texts.

Answer (score 1):

No way.
As it was already pointed out in comments, alternative text is designed for short (I mean, really short!) description of an image, like "Two people smiling and looking at each other".
What the alternative text lacks, is *navigation*: a screen reader by design conveys such a text to the user as a whole, so you can't fairly navigate through it, say, by line or by sentence. I'm not talking about really comfortable navigation like moving by heading, by paragraph, by structural element (list, table) and so on, and so forth.
So, if you just want the PDF look accessible-ish, do that, but it would be simply unfair to the blind people you design the document for. If, however, you really want to make it accessible, spend a couple extra hours and add the text and tag the document accordingly.
There is also an [article](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/acrobat/using/create-verify-pdf-accessibility.html) on Adobe about how to create accessible PDFs and verify their accessibility. They even have a "Make accessible" button, it seems.

Comment: Thank you. This confirms what I already thought to be true. I just needed some confirmation.